# Why isn't rspec failing on what should be a NameError inside a Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have an rspec that looks like:

```
it "should test nil" do
  u = Upload.new
  u.save!
  u.my_method!
end
```

The method looks like:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_method!
    puts "Made it to my method :)"
    not_defined_var
    puts "But didn't get this far :("
  end
end
```

Clearly, not_defined_var should give a "NameError: undefined local variable or method".

My output prints

```
Made it to my method :)
.

Finished in 1.54 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

I feel like I'm missing something essential. Got any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you have a `method_missing` defined somewhere that is swallowing it up?

Comment: I searched through my upload.rb and upload_spec.rb, and they weren't there. Could this be set in any other location? The problem is I can see errors in our production log -- so I think it's only getting ignored in some spec setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling method expect so Rspec is just passing. To compare if anything goes as expected you must call it. To test code you must compare the response with what you expect.

Example:

```
RSpec.describe Account do
  it "has a balance of zero when first created" do
    expect(Account.new.balance).to eq(Money.new(0))
  end
end
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using "expect { u.my_method! }.to change{ u.updated_at }"